# How to play .ima4 audio file in website

Tags: objective-c, audio, ima4

I have recently created an iPhone app where i recorded voice in .ima4 format. This application uploads these recordings to my web server, where user can play these recorded files.
But i don't know how to decode or play .ima4 files in a website.

Comment: your website is in which technology please mention.

Comment: My website is PHP based.
I tried to look for FFMPEG for conversion but didn't find anything useful in google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to use [html5](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html) for audio playing

Consider [this](http://www.wooji-juice.com/blog/iphone-openal-ima4-adpcm.html) link for workAround for ima4 format

Refer [soundmanager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/getstarted/#intro) link for playing audio in html